# VSTS extensions service endpoints

Tags: service, endpoint

I am trying to call a web api endpoint using VSTS extensions service endpoints.

I've created the endpoint in vsts but am looking for clues on how to call it from the extension in javascript. The endpoint will use basic authentication.

Existing documentation and code snippets seem sparse.

Comment: Hi, did you found a way to do it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968357/accessing-vsts-service-endpoints-from-javascript